# svn-keep receiving updates for a file without overriding the one in the remote repo

Tags: svn, version-control

I was given instructions to not overwrite the settings file for the remote repo. I modified the file I checked out so obviously it would now appear with an "M" on the status.

How will I be able to receive updates to the file without overwriting the remote file? (which means I must not apply my changes to my local copy)?

Sorry if I missed something here, I just started out with SVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Svn is gonna control that for you. When somebody changes the source code you did and he/she commit it to the server, when you update you code svn will merge the file on the server with your file. If both files have changed at the same line, snv will show you that you have a conflict and you will be able to edit it to fix. Then when you decide you can commit your code, svn you do the same thing.